# How to create massive with 5 obj and and draw them in the table?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do it with code like this. And I can't understand how to `document.write` all products and their all properties?

```
var products = [
    { name: 'Samsung Galaxy S8 64GB', count: 2, prise: 21999 },
    { name: 'Huawei P20 Lite 4/64GB Klein Blue', count: 0, prise: 11999 },
    { name: 'Lenovo K6 (K33a8) Grey', count: 0, prise: 3222 },
    { name: 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 3/32GB Snapdargon Black (Международная версия)', count: 4, prise: 4399 },
    { name: 'Samsung Galaxy A8 2018 32GB Black', count: 0, prise: 13999 },
];



document.write("<h>Product name</h3>");
for(var i=0; i < products.length; i++)
  document.write(products[i].name);
```

Comment: `document.write` is 1990's ... learn better methods (your code as shown should output names ... you just need to output `count` and `prise` as well in the same manner - but don't, because `document.write` is old)

Comment: What do you mean by drawing them into a table? I don't see any table in your code.

Comment: There are so many ways. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/us77c3qk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create a table out of the given products. You can do it like this.

```js
var products = [
    { name: 'Samsung Galaxy S8 64GB', count: 2, prise: 21999 },
    { name: 'Huawei P20 Lite 4/64GB Klein Blue', count: 0, prise: 11999 },
    { name: 'Lenovo K6 (K33a8) Grey', count: 0, prise: 3222 },
    { name: 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 3/32GB Snapdargon Black (Международная версия)', count: 4, prise: 4399 },
    { name: 'Samsung Galaxy A8 2018 32GB Black', count: 0, prise: 13999 },
];

// get the table
const table = document.querySelector('table');

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  // create a new table row and data cells
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  const cell1 = document.createElement('td');
  const cell2 = document.createElement('td');
  const cell3 = document.createElement('td');

  // populate cells with your products
  cell1.textContent = products[i].name;
  cell2.textContent = products[i].count;
  cell3.textContent = products[i].prise;

  // append cells to the row and row to the table
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: I put your code in my file main.js and here what I got : 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null .

Comment: @AlexeiiKozachuk Well it works here, do you have `<table></table>` in your html?